# Unit Of Work with Dependency injection Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, filter, dependency-injection, unit-of-work

I'm totally new to the asp.net framework. So my design pattern might be weird. Feel free to give me any advice. I would be appreciated it.

What I'm trying to do is to create a UnitOfWork to handle all repositories and using a filter to control transactions.

But there is a error comes up when I start the app.

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not
> able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType: ApplicationCore.Contracts.Services.ISubmissionService
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> Infrastructure.Services.SubmissionService': Unable to resolve service
> for type 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork': Unable to
> resolve service for type
> 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.)
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> ApplicationCore.Contracts.Services.ISubmissionService Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: Infrastructure.Services.SubmissionService': Unable
> to resolve service for type
> 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.  --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
> implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[]
> parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache
> lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain
> callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type
> serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type
> serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
> implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[]
> parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache
> lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain
> callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor
> serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1
> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection
> services, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()    at
> Program.$(String[] args) in
> /Users/shaoyulin/SoftwareDev/Antra-WEB/HRM/src/Recruiting/Recruiting.API/Program.cs:line
> 118  ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork': Unable to
> resolve service for type
> 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.  --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'ApplicationCore.Contracts.Repositories.IStatusRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'Infrastructure.Repositories.UnitOfWork'.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
> implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[]
> parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache
> lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain
> callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor
> serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
> descriptor)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1
> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)<---

It seems like they couldn't create the instance for UnitofWork. I'm not so sure.

Here are the codes. Any tips would be super appreciated!
Program.cs (register the service):

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddScoped<IJobService, JobService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubmissionService, SubmissionService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IJobRepository, JobRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubmissionRepository, SubmissionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICandidateRepository, CandidateRepository>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<LogFilter>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TransactionFilter>(sp =>
{
    var unitOfWork = sp.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
    return new TransactionFilter(unitOfWork);
});
```

SubmissionController:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("route")]
[TypeFilter(typeof(TransactionFilter))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine("in controller test");
    return Ok();
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly RecruitingDbContext _dbContext;
    private IDbContextTransaction _transaction;
    private bool _disposed;
    public ICandidateRepository CandidateRepository { get; }
    public IJobRepository JobRepository { get; }
    public IStatusRepository StatusRepository { get; }
    public ISubmissionRepository SubmissionRepository { get; }

    public UnitOfWork(RecruitingDbContext dbContext,
        ICandidateRepository candidateRepository,
        IJobRepository jobRepository,
        IStatusRepository statusRepository,
        ISubmissionRepository submissionRepository)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        CandidateRepository = candidateRepository;
        JobRepository = jobRepository;
        StatusRepository = statusRepository;
        SubmissionRepository = submissionRepository;
    }


    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        _transaction?.Commit();
        _transaction = null;
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        _transaction?.Rollback();
        _transaction = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _transaction?.Dispose();
        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

TransactionFilter:

```
public class TransactionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public TransactionFilter(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
        Console.WriteLine("start transaction");

        var resultContext = await next();

        if (resultContext.Exception == null)
        {
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
            _unitOfWork.CommitTransaction();
            Console.WriteLine("transaction committed");
            
        }
        else
        {
            _unitOfWork.RollbackTransaction();
            Console.WriteLine("transaction rollback");

        }
    }
}
```

And here is one of the Services: SubmissionService

```
public class SubmissionService : ISubmissionService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public SubmissionService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<bool> CheckEmailExist(SubmissionRequestModel submissionRequestModel)
    {
        var result =
            await _unitOfWork.SubmissionRepository.ListAsync(s => s.Candidate.Email == submissionRequestModel.Email);
        return result.Count > 0;
    }

    public async Task<int> AddSubmission(SubmissionRequestModel submissionRequestModel, int jobId)
    {
        Candidate candidate = new Candidate
        {
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
            Email = submissionRequestModel.Email,
            FirstName = submissionRequestModel.FirstName,
            LastName = submissionRequestModel.LastName,
        };
        Submission submission = new Submission
        {
            JobId = jobId,
            SubmittedOn = DateTime.Now,
            RejectedReason = ""
        };
        var candiateResult = await _unitOfWork.CandidateRepository.AddAsync(candidate);
        var submissionResult = await _unitOfWork.SubmissionRepository.AddAsync(submission);
        return submissionResult.JobId;
    }

    public async Task<List<SubmissionResponseModel>> GetAllSubmissionByJobId(int jobId)
    {
        return await _unitOfWork.SubmissionRepository.GetAllSubmisionByJobId(jobId);
    }
}
```

SubmissionRepository:

```
public class SubmissionRepository : BaseRepository<Submission>, ISubmissionRepository
{
    // using DI
    private RecruitingDbContext _dbContext;

    // constructor for DI
    public SubmissionRepository(RecruitingDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    // public int AddSubmission(Candidate candidate, Submission submission)
    // {
    //     // return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    //
    //     using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    //     {
    //         try
    //         {
    //             var can = _dbContext.Candidates.Add(candidate);
    //             _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    //             submission.CandidateId = can.Entity.Id;
    //             _dbContext.Submissions.Add(submission);
    //             _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    //
    //             transaction.Commit();
    //             return 1;
    //         }
    //         catch (Exception ex)
    //         {
    //             transaction.Rollback();
    //             return 0;
    //         }
    //     }
    // }

    public async Task<List<SubmissionResponseModel>> GetAllSubmisionByJobId(int jobId)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Submissions
            .Join(_dbContext.Candidates,
                s => s.CandidateId,
                c => c.Id,
                (s, c) => new
                {
                    s.Id,
                    s.JobId,
                    s.CandidateId,
                    c.FirstName,
                    c.LastName,
                    c.Email
                })
            .Join(_dbContext.Jobs,
                o => o.JobId,
                j => j.Id,
                (o, j) => new
                {
                    o.Id,
                    o.JobId,
                    o.FirstName,
                    o.LastName,
                    o.Email
                })
            .Where(o2 => o2.JobId == jobId)
            .Select(o2 => new SubmissionResponseModel
            {
                FirstName = o2.FirstName,
                LastName = o2.LastName,
                Email = o2.Email
            }).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

BaseRepository:

```
public class SubmissionRepository : BaseRepository<Submission>, ISubmissionRepository
{
    // using DI
    private RecruitingDbContext _dbContext;

    // constructor for DI
    public SubmissionRepository(RecruitingDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    // public int AddSubmission(Candidate candidate, Submission submission)
    // {
    //     // return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    //
    //     using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    //     {
    //         try
    //         {
    //             var can = _dbContext.Candidates.Add(candidate);
    //             _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    //             submission.CandidateId = can.Entity.Id;
    //             _dbContext.Submissions.Add(submission);
    //             _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    //
    //             transaction.Commit();
    //             return 1;
    //         }
    //         catch (Exception ex)
    //         {
    //             transaction.Rollback();
    //             return 0;
    //         }
    //     }
    // }

    public async Task<List<SubmissionResponseModel>> GetAllSubmisionByJobId(int jobId)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Submissions
            .Join(_dbContext.Candidates,
                s => s.CandidateId,
                c => c.Id,
                (s, c) => new
                {
                    s.Id,
                    s.JobId,
                    s.CandidateId,
                    c.FirstName,
                    c.LastName,
                    c.Email
                })
            .Join(_dbContext.Jobs,
                o => o.JobId,
                j => j.Id,
                (o, j) => new
                {
                    o.Id,
                    o.JobId,
                    o.FirstName,
                    o.LastName,
                    o.Email
                })
            .Where(o2 => o2.JobId == jobId)
            .Select(o2 => new SubmissionResponseModel
            {
                FirstName = o2.FirstName,
                LastName = o2.LastName,
                Email = o2.Email
            }).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: That's a very long question with a lot of details. Would you mind reducing this to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE). This lowers the barrier for others to help you. A great way to build an MRE is to start from an empty project and add code until you get the error; then try to remove as much code while not removing the error. The code that's left would be a good candidate for an MRE that you can post here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I would close this question and start a new one.